# 401 Unauthorized For the Post Method in WooCommerce API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angular, typescript, woocommerce

First of all i'll show you my complete code to understand the issue

This is the woocommerce api auth with the cosumer key and secret of the file checkout.ts

```js
      this.WooCommerce = WC({
        url:"http://localhost/wordpress/",
        consumerKey:"ck_429c9a4521b73420e6c6d57179ab2b19350fbdb8",
        consumerSecret:"cs_b9aaa8b11d15a6132abca0a8b5ca324fcfa76f87",
        

      });
```

and this is the post Method for the order for the checkout.ts file of the function placeOrder().

```js
      this.WooCommerce.postAsync("orders", orderData).then ((data) => {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(data.body).order);

        let response = (JSON.parse(data.body).order);

        this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: "Order Placed Successfully",
          message: "Your order has been placed successfully. Your order number is " + response.order_number,
          buttons: [{
            text: "OK",
            handler: () => {
              this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
            }
          }]
        }).present();

      })
```

This is the html file checkout.html

```html
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newOrder.billing_address.first_name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      
      ....
      
      <button ion-button block color="danger" (click)="placeOrder()">Place Order</button>
```

and when i click to the place order button it show for me this error

[image]

i search for this issue in some forum and they suggest for me to add some code to the woocommerce api auth after the consumer key & secret like

```
verifySsl: false,
queryStringAuth: true
```

Also to add some code into the .httaccess file like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
RewriteRule ^(.) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

and i still have the same probleme in the console and this is the netword result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com', // Your store URL
  consumerKey: 'consumer_key', // Your consumer key
  consumerSecret: 'consumer_secret', // Your consumer secret
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});
```

so as per their [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#authentication-over-http) you are using OAUTH 1.0 authorization strategy , so the above is the basic WooCommerce object signature and properties.

Comment: can you clear cache and cookies and try once @MohamedAliLassoued

Comment: are you sure the key you generated was for http authentication and not for https?
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http